# Click to copy each attribute href of a tag into image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My image link sources in for loop

```
  foreach (images as image) { 

 echo ?> <a id="image" onclick="return false;" href=" my image link"  >
          <span > <?php  echo  $image->imageName; ?></span> <?
    }
```

Output for image link something like
**Link1**
**Link2**
**Link3**

HTML to show image

```
<img id="copyimage" src="" alt="No Pic" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

My Jquery

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image").click(function(){

  var link = $(this).attr('href');

    $("#copyimage").attr("src", link);

});
});
```

when I click to each link (Link1 Link2 Link3) ,I want to copy each of them into image source to show image. But it just only worked for first link (Link1) and Link2 Link2 didn't.

Comment: It's because they all have the same id and jQuery will only return the first match when using an id selector.

Comment: You are giving the same id to each link.

Comment: use class name instead of ID .

Comment: you can use same ID to muiltiple elements

Comment: Also, use `prop()` over `attr()` where possible

Answer (score 0):

all the link have the some ID `id="image"` you need to use class :

```
foreach (images as image) { 

 echo ?> <a class="image" onclick="return false;" href=" my image link"  >
          <span > <?php  echo  $image->imageName; ?></span> <?
    }
```

Jquery

```
(document).ready(function(){
        $(".image").click(function(){

      var link = $(this).attr('href');

        $("#copyimage").attr("src", link);

    });
```

Comment: Alternatively use a data-attribute `data-id` for code purpose in case the CSS guys remove the class if they don't need it.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot :D